# Kato's Font Style

Tags: fonts, lyx-layouts

Does anyone know the font style used in Kato's *Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators*?  Better yet, does anyone know of a TeX package or style file that replicates the layout and style used throughout Kato's book?

Comment: For the first half of your question, see [this TeX.SX post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/55879).